# Missing data and Attributes selection

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining

My data is 1,785,000 records with 271 features. I'm trying to reduce number of features used to build the model.

Q1.  while exploring the data I found that some features are almost all missing data, like only 25 records has value for this feature and the others records has missing values, so I thought that is not informative enough and it's better to eleminate those features, am I right? and if I am right, for what level I can do that, I mean if 90%, 80%, etc.. of each feature are missing values, when I can decide to get rid of these features? (taking in consideration that it is the dependent variable is N/Y and only %1.157 of the whole data is belonging to Y).

Q2. for each individual in the dataset, there are 64 trait_type listed, where each one can take one of the values [1 or 3 or 5]. my question is: if some trait-type take only value [5] or missing dat for all the record, does it have any value or again we can eliminate that feature?

Q3. if the choice is to delete these features, how to delete column from data.frame in R?

Thank you

**Update:**
I'm trying to use `caret` package to do the variable selection.
I applied this:

```
ctrl<- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, method="cv", verbose = FALSE, returnResamp= 
"final")

lmprofile<- rfe(x,y, sizes = subsets, rfeControl = ctrl)
```

where `x` is the data.frame that have 270 dependant variables and y is the factor of the independent variable which has value Y/N. I got this error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"
enter code here
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

any help please?

Comment: Here is one way to delete a column, by it's index number: `dat <- dat[,-1]` which would delete the first column. Here is another way, deleting columns by their name: `dat <- dat[,-which(colnames(dat)=="YourColumnName")]` Your other questions might be better asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com since they are not really about programming. Q1, my guess would be to do a PCA or similar data reduction/structure detection on all the data to find the variables that contribute the most to differences between the features and just use those variables. Q2, see previous, probably yes.

Comment: I would suggest you split this into three question. Only Question 3 is appropriate for SO, though. First two should go to crossvalidated.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just because much of your data in one column is missing doesn't mean that column will not be predictive, it's just the same as having many of the same value in that column.

Of course there is a cutoff, if that column can only help you distinguish between a few cases (of many) then it can be removed and could only affect overall model strength a little.

To help you decide whether to keep the column, you could build a univariate model with it - where the dataset just includes that column and the dependant variable, and look at the strength of that model.  If it's not much better than random, then it's probably safe to drop the column.